# inverse of randomly generated binary matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have generated binary non singular matrix of size 602*602

```
l = 602;
w = round (rand (l,l));
```

now I want to find the inverse of this matrix in binary form, I tried this command

```
 w_inv = mod(inv(w),2)
```

but the result is not in binary form. HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Communications Systems Toolbox installed inverse in GF(2) can be obtained as simply as

```
>> l = 602;
>> w = gf(round(rand (l,l)));
>> whos
  Name        Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  l           1x1                    8  double              
  w         602x602            1450156  gf                  

>> b = inv(w);
>> all(all(b*w == eye(l,l)))

ans =

     1

>> all(all(w*b == eye(l,l)))

ans =

     1

>>
```

cfr. [Galois Field Computations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp5602) and [Create Galois field array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gf.html).
BTW, over the real field the determinant of w is not infinite, just to big to be represented as an IEEE floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the way you generate the matrix `w` doesn't assure it will be non-singular; only that in most cases it will be.

Leaving that aside, the inverse of `w` is `inv(w)`. That's the *only* matrix that multiplied by `w` will give the identity matrix. And of course, the inverse matrix will not be binary (or even integer-valued) in general. If you apply `mod(,... ,2)` to the inverse it ceases to be the inverse matrix.

---

A different question would be to find an inverse matrix in [GF(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29), that is, using modulo-2 addition. If that's your case, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/49002).

Comment: the matrix is non singular as <gf(w) = 602> and yes the main issue is to find inverse matrix in gf(2) ,but the matrix *w* has infinity determinant, so I can't implement the solution you proposed. How can I generate a random binary matrix which is invertible and has finite determinant ?

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by _gf(w) = 602_? And how can _w_ possibly have infinity determinant?

Comment: sorry ..I meant galois field rank of the matrix thus **gfrank(w)=602** and when I execute the command **det (w)**,   result is Inf, That why I can't compute *mod(det(w)*inv(w),2)*.